# Full screen background in Swift and Spritekit showing black bars

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i have googled the problem and tried the following:

- Adding Launch Images
- Adding different size background images
- changed the fill modes

yet im still getting black bars on the xcode simulator on iphone 6.

My gamecontroller looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var scene : GameScene!

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let skView = view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true

        scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }


}
```

My Gamescene

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    required init?(coder aDecoder:NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(size: CGSize){
        super.init(size: size)

        var tempText = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Copperplate")
        tempText.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
        tempText.text = "Click anywhere to play"
        tempText.fontSize = 20

        addChild(tempText)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {



        var newScene = LevelOne(size: size)
        var transition = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(2)

        view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: transition);
    }


}
```

and my firstlevel

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class LevelOne : SKScene{

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bgsmaller")
    let player = SKSpriteNode()

    required init?(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)

        // add background

        background.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: 0.0)
        addChild(background)



    }


}
```

any advice would be appreciated.  I am new to swift and spriteKit so I don't know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 7 is out now, so I'd update to that. It might fix that bug with the simulator, but it also lets developers test their apps on their physical iDevices for free (no $99 per year licence required), so then you could see if the glitch exists in your code or in the Xcode IDE, that is if you have an iPhone, iPad, or iPod Touch.